# Определяемое слово для причастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксический-разбор, причастный-оборот

[Будущая свекровь напоминала экспонат из Музея мадам Тюссо.] **То же совершенство, отточенная элегантность, красота, словно слеза янтаря(?) застывшая во времени, и извечная приятная прохлада, остужающая любые эмоции.**
[**А. Миронова. И дам вам сердце новое**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=FFcyDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT33&lpg=PT33&dq=%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=CbBGUz4vsk&sig=qoxzStYjEntUEtyl7bBhFWxGMS8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBnprzirXbAhUK3aQKHS6nAbMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8&f=false)

1. Никак не могу понять: какое из существительных (*красота* или *слеза*) является определяемым словом.
2. Очень хочется поставить запятую в указанном месте (ее нет и в печатном варианте — об это я и "споткнулась" при чтении книги). Нужна ли она?

Answer (score 3):

> То же совершенство, отточенная элегантность, красота, словно слеза
>   янтаря застывшая во времени, и извечная приятная прохлада,
>   остужающая любые эмоции.

Определяемое слово здесь "красота". Причастный оборот: "словно слеза янтаря застывшая во времени". Границы причастного оборота: застывшая (где?) — во времени; застывшая (как?) — словно слеза янтаря. Запятая не нужна.

Для того, чтобы предложение можно было прочесть с определяемым словом "слеза", его нужно изменить.

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, автор хотел выразить такой смысл: **красота** дамы (которой та напоминала восковую фигуру) **казалась застывшей** во времени - *подобно тому, как застывает слеза янтаря*. Этому соответствует вариант **без запятой**; его можно перефразировать так:

> То же совершенство, отточенная элегантность, красота, *подобно слезе
>   янтаря застывшая во времени*, ...

Если же поставить запятую,

> красота, словно слеза янтаря, застывшая во времени

то смысл становится другим, менее естественным и даже двойственным:

- красота подобна слезе янтаря, и она застыла во времени
- красота подобна слезе янтаря, застывшей во времени.

Эти оттенки смысла даже трудно различить между собой по грамматическим признакам. Поэтому с выбором корректора (без запятой) можно согласиться.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение не назовешь удачным, так как **всё в нём неясно и двойственно: смысл, грамматика, структура, интонация.** В таком виде его трудно понять, трудно прочитать и подобрать подходящее правило для постановки знаков препинания.

Я понимаю смысл так: её внешность перестала меняться с годами, её красота будто застыла во времени, как слеза янтаря.

Эту мысль можно выразить так:

**То же совершенство, отточенная элегантность, красота, застывшая во времени, словно слеза янтаря, и извечная приятная прохлада, остужающая любые эмоции.**

Comment: Да, спасибо, Вы развеяли мои сомнения (я бы написала точно так же). Меня смущало сравнение, ведь янтарь - по определению - уже и есть застывшая капля (слеза).

Comment: "Слеза янтаря" часто используется в качестве сравнения, например:  Взгляд бесконечно нежный, Словно слеза янтаря.